# Local file copy using SMB shares

Tags: networking, samba

I created two SMB shares for my local disks on my server: `disk1` and `disk2`. Using my laptop I can access the shares. If I try to copy files between these two shares using my laptop the speed is very bad due to my wifi speed.

Is there a way to do the "copy job" as a local job on the server instead of sending the data through my slow wifi connection? I would like to organize my data on my server but that's impossible with this slow connection.

Comment: Do you have shell access on the server? And can you change the configuration (temporarily) to have it become one share? It is a slow via-client operation now *because* these are two different shares.

Comment: The shares are on different disks. I don't think I can combine them? I could use the ssh terminal to organize my data, but that's not very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

The I/O (copy) operation between *two different shares* does not take place efficiently on the remote side. Instead, all data is being transferred via the client. This is by design of the CIFS/SMB protocol. I can think of two workarounds.

---

#### Use SFTP

SFTP is built-in to SSH in Ubuntu, so you already have it once you have OpenSSH server installed. In Nautilus, you can do this either using the menu or by entering a manual location.

[image]

And browse in your file manager as you would using the command-line way as `user`.

Command-line way: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get a textual location bar. Then use this as the location:

```
sftp://user@hostname
```

On KDE (Dolphin), it's

```
fish://user@hostname
```

---

#### Make them one share

If you prefer to stick with CIFS/SMB access, then the only option I see is to make them one share. You can even make it an additional share or have them there just temporarily.

First, make sure they're mounted on a similar level of folders, e.g.

```
/mnt
└── shares
    ├── disk1
    └── disk2
```

And then just share `/mnt/shares`.